# Belkin Router Manager were to download

Tags: download, drivers, router

Basically i wish to do this

http://en-us-support.belkin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3796

but i cannot find the belkin router manager anywere,

Does anybody have it ?

Thanks

Mason

Comment: A consumer-level router that requires software? What a joke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't suppose this is what you're looking for?

http://en-us-support.belkin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3712/p/5133